# How do I adjust only one handle on a curve in the graph editor?

Tags: bezier-curves

In After Effects I could grab a handle on a curve, hold down a modifier key, and only one side of the curve would be affected.. Is this possible in Blender in the Graph Editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change handle type to free, then you can move just one handle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's always the more beautiful answer that wins :D

Comment: Not always. But nobody stops you to make beautiful answers 

Comment: Usually when I make beautiful answers I often do not post them, because other people are quicker than me and my answer becomes obsolete... but being quicker doesn't help me when my answer isn't so attractive as we see :D

Comment: Then just make them even more beautiful ;) well...although there are lots of different people here, one thing (i think) we have in common: we are highly visual oriented people. So if there are animated gifs in the answer (and i can tell it from my own experience) it is much easier to understand the answer by an animation (if it is good and easy to understand) than reading text. And of course i also like to thank the answerer by its work and effort, but often i don't know how to decide: the quicker one or the one with more effort... ;)

Answer (score 5):

That depends on how the handles are set. By default, on a Bézier curve the handle type is set to *Aligned*, that's why both sides of the curve are affected. If you select a keyframe and press <kbd>V</kbd> you get the *Set Keyframe Handle Type* context menu. There you can choose *Free*.

If you want these *Free* handles temporarily to affect both sides without changing it back, you can select them both and use <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate or <kbd>S</kbd> to scale them together.